# Angular checkmark for list elements

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to have checkmarks in a list for those list elements where a certain condition is met.

**My Html:**

```
<div class="col col-70" ng-if="showBothEnterLists">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="w in word_pair | limitTo:4">
            <input placeholder="Enter word" type="text" ng-model="word">
            <input placeholder="Enter pair" type="text" ng-model="pair" ng-change="check(word, pair)">
            <div ng-show="showCheckMark" align="right"><i class="ion-checkmark myCheckmark"></i></div>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </div>
```

**Corresponding code in my controller:**

```
$scope.word_pair = [

  {'word':'Carla', 'pair':'Lion'},
  {'word':'Sophie', 'pair':'Lotta'},
  {'word':'Jannes', 'pair':'Stubbi'},
  {'word':'Martin', 'pair':'Wolle'},
  {'word':'Flo', 'pair':'Ign'},
  {'word':'Rere', 'pair':'Rose'},
  {'word':'Jean', 'pair':'Tamara'},
  {'word':'Memo', 'pair':'Elk'},
  {'word':'Nila', 'pair':'Naph'}

  ]
...

$scope.check = function(word, pair) {     
  for(var i=0; i < $scope.word_pair.length; i++) {       
   if($scope.word_pair[i].word == word && $scope.word_pair[i].pair == pair) {    
    $scope.showCheckMark=true
    $scope.checkCount++
  }
 }
}
```

However, this code gives me checkmarks for all list items when condition for the first item is met.

[image]

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE without remapping**

create an object in your scope that will hold the user's answers

```
$scope.answers = {}
```

set the ng-model of each input in conjunction with the `$index`

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="w in word_pair | limitTo:4">
   <input placeholder="Enter word" type="text" ng-model="answers['word'+$index]">
   input placeholder="Enter pair" type="text" ng-model="answers['pair'+$index]" ng-change="check(word, pair)">
   <div ng-show="showCheckMark(answers['word'+$index], answers['pair'+$index])" align="right"><i class="ion-checkmark myCheckmark"></i>asdadas</div>
</ion-item>
```

Finally the only thing showCheckMark has to do is check if the key and value exist

```
$scope.showCheckMark = function(word, pair){
  return $scope.word_pair.filter( item => item.word == word && item.pair == pair).length;
}
```

Here is a working example in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jAkaQN)

Comment: Can you suggest any such condition? w.word && w.pair by defaults fills all the input boxes and checkmarks, but natural.

Comment: @Nitish you need to show the checkmark if the word and pair inserted exist in the same object?

Comment: Yes correct! When inserted word and pair combination exists in the array word_pair, then a checkmark

Comment: The problem with remaping is it is breaking my other functionality. This checking both input boxes comes in 6th level of the game I am developing, first 5 levels has totally different requirements. My working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/0y3pad?p=preview This has complete code, and might be overwhelming to go through, see if you can! Also return $scope.word_pair[word] && $scope.word_pair[word] = pair; throws an error saying left side assignment is invalid

Comment: @Nitish re-updated. Change the ng-repeat and in showCheckMark filter all elements that have the same word and pair and get the length of the returned array. if there is a match it will return a truthy value and the checkbox will be show

Comment: This one by defaults fills all the input boxes and checkmarks!

Comment: @Nitish updated again with example solution to codepen